# Nested clusters (or add_subgraph) on pygraphviz

Tags: graphviz, pygraphviz

With pygraphviz, I can add subgraphs with `add_subgraph(list_of_nodes, label='cluster_somename')`. This will create it inside a subgraph block when `layout` is called.

Is there a way to nest the subgraphs?

I'm using the `dot` layout, I know it can handle and display subclusters if they are nested. But I can't get pygraphviz to output nested clusters.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the subgraph's `add_subgraph()` to create a nested subgraph.

```
import pygraphviz as pgv

g = pgv.AGraph(name='root')
g.add_node('A')

g.add_subgraph(name='cluster_1')
c1 = g.subgraphs()[-1]
c1.add_node('B')

c1.add_subgraph(name='cluster_2')
c2 = c1.subgraphs()[-1]
c2.add_node('C')

print(g)
```

```
strict graph root {
    subgraph cluster_1 {
        subgraph cluster_2 {
            C;
        }
        B;
    }
    A;
}
```