# Getting pygraphviz clusters to point at each other? (And render properly.)

Tags: python, graphviz, dot, pygraphviz

I have seen some posts talking about this sort of thing, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012036/graphviz-how-to-connect-subgraphs), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46646181/connect-graphviz-cluster-to-itself), but I've recreated that graphviz spec and it's not rendering the same. In particular, where an arrow should be starting from a cluster edge and pointing at a node, it instead disappears at that edge and only the head appears at the node.

Here's the code:

```
G = nx.DiGraph(name='G')
G.add_nodes_from(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])
A = to_agraph(G, compound=True)

cluster0 = A.add_subgraph(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], name='cluster0')
cluster1 = A.add_subgraph(['e', 'f', 'g'], name='cluster1')

cluster0.add_edges_from([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')])
cluster1.add_edges_from([('e', 'g'), ('e', 'f')])

A.add_edges_from([('c', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'g'), ('d', 'h')])#, ('d', 'e'), ])
A.get_edge('c', 'e').attr.update({'ltail': 'cluster0'})
```

Which produces:

```
strict digraph G {
    graph [compound=True,
        name=G
    ];
    subgraph cluster1 {
        e -> f;
        e -> g;
    }
    subgraph cluster0 {
        a -> b;
        a -> c;
        b -> d;
        c -> d;
    }
    b -> f;
    c -> e  [ltail=cluster0];
    c -> g;
    d -> h;
}
```

And to render the AGraph, I do:

```
A.layout(prog='dot')
png_str = A.draw(format='png', prog='dot', args=f"-Gdpi={DPI}")
sio = BytesIO(png_str)
img = mpimg.imread(sio)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Which renders as:

[Broken Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8oFv.png)

Knocking out the ltail=cluster0 attribute (`#A.get_edge('c', 'e').attr.update({'ltail': 'cluster0'})`), the image comes out to:

[Full Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsUMV.png)

What am I doing wrong? (Huge bonus points if in showing me what I've done wrong, you also show an arrow whose tail starts on the border of the interior of two nested clusters and points outside of the outermost one.)

Comment: Your code triggers a `TypeError` and a `NameError` due to `compound=True` and `DPI`, respectively. Also, note that using `A = to_agraph(G)` yields full arrows. But I'm still unclear about your expected output/configuration. Could you manually specify it on one of the screenshots ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, bad news and (maybe) good news.
Good news: Nothing wrong with the produced **dot** input.
Bad news: You are encountering this bug (https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/2447)
Good news:  It seems to be fixed in the latest release(s).  This version (dot - graphviz version 10.0.0~dev.20240113.0503 (20240113.0503)) produced:
[image]

(sorry, don't quite understand you "bonus points" question)

Comment: Nice! Installing pygraphviz via conda seems to install a version of graphviz with this bug, but manually installing graphviz (in my case, through conda-forge, version 2.50.0) fixes it! The bonus points mission, if you choose to accept it, is: Suppose there was a nested cluster "cluster0_inner" containing "a, b, c" within cluster0 (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986684/nested-clusters-or-add-subgraph-on-pygraphviz)). Now get an arrow whose tail is on the border of cluster0_inner and whose head points to node "h".

Comment: ...I seem to have failed to make a minimal repro (as in: it's working when I minimize it.) So, I'm gonna investigate and make a note here if I solve it.

Comment: It was just user error. I was putting the wrong cluster name in for the ltail attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers the bonus Q:

```
strict digraph G {
    graph [compound=True,
        name=G
    ];
    subgraph cluster1 {
        e -> f;
        e -> g;
    }
    subgraph cluster0 {
      subgraph cluster0_inner {
        color=red
        a  b c
      }
        a -> b;
        a -> c;
        b -> d;
        c -> d;
    }
    b -> f;
    c -> e  [ltail=cluster0];
    c -> g;
    d -> h;
    b->h [ltail=cluster0_inner]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Not quite. The sort of thing I was looking for was this: 


strict digraph G {
 graph [compound=True,
  name=G
 ];
 subgraph cluster1 {
  subgraph cluster1_inner {
   c;
  }
  d;
 }
 subgraph cluster0 {
  subgraph cluster0_inner {
   a;
  }
  b;
 }
 a -> c [ltail=cluster0_inner];
}

Unfortunately, whatever is going right here is not going right in my larger application. Will investigate.

Comment: It was just user error. I was putting the wrong cluster name in for the ltail attribute. Thanks! The minimal code I posted above this comment generalizes as expected.